# Flutter Finished with error: ProcessException: Permission denied

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, flutter

I want to run my frist app with flutter but I got the following error :

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode.
Initializing gradle.
Resolving dependencies.
Finished with error shown below:

> ProcessException: Permission denied   Command:
>   /home/abdoul-razak/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt dump xmltree
>   /home/abdoul-razak/Projects/akoybiz/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk
>   AndroidManifest.xml

here is the result of `flutter doctor`:

```
abdoul-razak@Komche:~/Projects/akoybiz$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

after updating the sdk android here is the result of `flutter doctor -v`

```
 abdoul-razak@Komche:~/Projects/akoybiz$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at /home/abdoul-razak/flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (il y a 9 semaines), 2018-11-29 19:41:26
      -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/abdoul-razak/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/abdoul-razak/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 23.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 171.4424
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 2.22.2

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • itel P31 • 45YP8LSO4T7HWCLZ • android-arm • Android 7.0 (API 24)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Seems like some license acceptance issue. Please provide your result for `flutter doctor` command

Comment: Here is the result                                                                                                        abdoul-razak@Komche:~/Projects/akoybiz$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Linux, locale fr_FR.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Thanks. It's better to add these kinds of replies as a question edit. anyway please find the solution section.

Comment: Make sure the following files are marked as executable https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20364#issuecomment-480373990

Comment: It could be an issue with your java perhaps? make sure its exported correctly

Answer (score 4):

The issue is related to your Android SDK licenses. Run the command

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Then press `y` until it acquires all permissions.

Answer (score 3):

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ./gradlew
```

By using this command it solves the issue. I don't know the exact reason but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same exception. And something fixed it, but I do not know what exactly.

The exception says something different but I think it has something to do where flutter is installed. I reinstalled it again like suggested on their [website](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux) and it worked...

```
 cd ~/development
 tar xf ~/Downloads/flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable.tar.xz
```

Edit: Make sure you use a local folder for your flutter project too.